# How to add a Name=Value pair to the RzCheckList component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, checklistbox

In a Delphi Win32 VCL Application, I use the `TRzCheckList` component that is similar to the standard `TCheckListBox` but has several additional features.

`TRzCheckList` is part of the included "Konopka Signature VCL Controls" available for free from the GetIt Package Manager in the Delphi IDE:

[image]

I try to add a "Name=Value" pair to the RzCheckList with this code:

```
ThisItem := RzCheckList1.AddItemToGroup(0, 'MyName');
RzCheckList1.Items.ValueFromIndex[ThisItem] := 'MyValue';
```

However, instead of getting "MyName" displayed in the RzCheckList (with "MyValue" as a hidden part of the item), I get this at run-time:

[image]

Similarly, when using this code:

```
RzCheckList1.Items.AddPair('MyName', 'MyValue');
```

...I get this result:

[image]

So, how to add a Name=Value pair to the RzCheckList component and have only the Name part displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to add the pair to a specific Group:

```
RzCheckList1.AddItemToGroup(0, 'MyName=MyValue');
```

Then implement this code in the `OnDrawItem` event-handler:

```
procedure TformMain.RzCheckList1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  Flags: Longint;
  Data: String;
  FCanvas: TCanvas;
  CheckListBox: TCheckListBox;
begin
  CheckListBox := TCheckListBox(Control);
  FCanvas := CheckListBox.Canvas;
  FCanvas.FillRect(Rect);
  if Index < CheckListBox.Count then
  begin
    Flags := DrawTextBiDiModeFlags(DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_NOPREFIX);
    if not UseRightToLeftAlignment then
      Inc(Rect.Left, 2)
    else
      Dec(Rect.Right, 2);
    Data := CheckListBox.Items.Names[Index];

    DrawText(FCanvas.Handle, Data, Length(Data), Rect, Flags);
  end;
end;
```

This gets you the desired result at run-time:

[image]